# TFS Issue: Projects missing in the Source Control Explorer's left pane

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

i am having an issue in the TFS. I am able to login to my TFS account but i am not able to access any project and its files in my visual studio 2012. Also, the Folder pane on the left hand side in source control explorer is not loading any projects. Its blank.
What am i supposed to do?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Is it the first time you login TFS? How did you login your TFS? Have you connect to TFS in Team Explorer?

Comment: You may post a screenshot of your Team Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things need to be checked:

1. Make sure your VS has the latest update installed (Requires latest Visual Studio 2012 update. Supports Git with Visual Studio Tools for Git extension.).
2. Make sure there are team projects under the Collection you connect.
3. Contact the administrator to see whether you have the permission to read the project.

Comment: Thanks Cece, for your reply. As you suggested i contacted the administrator and found that the access level for my TFS login was set to 'Stackholder' which is the free access. So i suppose paid licence for my login must have expired, this is why i was degraded to 'Stackholder'. Now the administrator has changed my access level to 'Basic'. Now i can access the code through TFS.